# DropDown Menu Display Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

What I want to do in my website is to have the following code displayed just like its appears but with a timeout for closing the menu when hovering over a menu section (at the bottom is the problematic code).

[This is what I achieved](http://jsfiddle.net/martinbuzzetti/hjeLF/) without having any troubles (but without the timeout when hovering over the menu sections)

CSS:

```css
.menu
{
   list-style:none;
   position:relative;
}
ul.menu ul
{
   list-style:none;
   display:none;
   position:absolute;   /* To be the position relative to <li> that contains the <ul> */
   left:5em;        /* So there is no overlaping over <li> */
   top:-1em;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul
{
   display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li>Equipos
        <ul>
            <li>Masculinos
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Aguilas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cef 18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Celtas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indios 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indios 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Isotopos</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Femeninos
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cef 18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Celtas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facdef</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Isotopos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parque Sur</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Categorias
        <ul>
            <li>Primera Masculino</li>
            <li>Primera Femenino</li>
            <li>Reserva Masculino</li>
            <li>Reserva Femenino</li>
            <li>Inferiores</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Torneos
        <ul>
            <li>Apertura</li>
            <li>Anual</li>
            <li>Clausura</li>
            <li>Torneo de la Independencia</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Canchas
        <ul>
            <li>Cef 18</li>
            <li>Celtas</li>
            <li>Indios</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Resultados</li>
        <li>Posiciones</li>
        <li>Estadisticas</li>
        <li>Boletines ATS</li>
        <li>Arbitros y Designaciones</li>
    </ul>
```

[And the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/martinbuzzetti/LSVXm/):

CSS:

```css
#navigation_horiz {width:820px; clear:both; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 auto;}
#navigation_horiz  ul {height:50px; display:block;background:blue}
#navigation_horiz  ul li {display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:50px; background:#999; margin:0 1px 0 0; position:relative}
#navigation_horiz  ul li a.navlink {display:block; width:200px; height:30px; padding: 20px 0 0 0; text-align:center; color:#fff; text-decoration:none}
#navigation_horiz .dropdown {position:absolute; padding:20px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px}
#navigation_horiz ul li #dropdown_style {background:#ccc; color:#fff}
#navigation_horiz ul li #dropdown_style a {color:red}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation_horiz">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Equipos</a>
            <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style">            
                <a href="" class="navlink">Masculinos</a>
                <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Aguilas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cef 18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Celtas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Indios 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Indios 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Isotopos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="" class="navlink">Femeninos</a>
                <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Cef 18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Celtas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facdef</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Indias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Isotopos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Parque Sur</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .dropdown_menu -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Categorias</a>
            <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style">            
                <ul>
                    <li>Primera Masculino</li>
                    <li>Primera Femenino</li>
                    <li>Reserva Masculino</li>
                    <li>Reserva Femenino</li>
                    <li>Inferiores</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- .dropdown_menu -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Torneos</a>
            <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style">            
                <ul>
                    <li>Apertura</li>
                    <li>Anual</li>
                    <li>Clausura</li>
                    <li>Torneo de la Independencia</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- .dropdown_menu -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Canchas</a>
            <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_style">            
                <ul>
                    <li>Cef 18</li>
                    <li>Celtas</li>
                    <li>Indios</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- .dropdown_menu -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Resultados</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Posiciones</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Estadisticas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Boletines</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="navlink">Arbitros y Designaciones</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- #navigation_horiz -->
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.naviDropDown = function(options)
    {
        //set up default options 
        var defaults={
        dropDownClass: 'dropdown', //the class name for your drop down
        dropDownWidth: 'auto',  //the default width of drop down elements
        slideDownEasing: 'easeInOutCirc', //easing method for slideDown
        slideUpEasing: 'easeInOutCirc', //easing method for slideUp
        slideDownDuration: 500, //easing duration for slideDown
        slideUpDuration: 1000, //easing duration for slideUp
        orientation: 'vertical' //orientation - either 'horizontal' or 'vertical'
        };
        var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);     
        return this.each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('width', opts.dropDownWidth).css('display', 'none');
            var buttonWidth = $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).parent().width() + 'px';
            var buttonHeight = $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).parent().height() + 'px';
            if(opts.orientation == 'horizontal')
            {
                $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', '0px').css('top', buttonHeight);
            }
            if(opts.orientation == 'vertical')
            {
                $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', buttonWidth).css('top', '0px');
            }
            $this.find('ul').hoverIntent(function() {}, hideDropDown);
            $this.find('li').hoverIntent(getDropDown, function() {});
        });
        var activeNav = null;
        function getDropDown()
        {
            var newActiveNav = $(this);
            if (activeNav && activeNav.get(0) !== newActiveNav.get(0))
            {
                hideDropDown();
            }
            if (!activeNav)
            {
                showDropDown(newActiveNav);
            }
            activeNav = newActiveNav;
        }

        function showDropDown(newActiveNav)
        {        newActiveNav.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).slideDown({duration:opts.slideDownDuration, easing:opts.slideDownEasing});
        }

        function hideDropDown()
        {
            if (activeNav)
            {    activeNav.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).slideUp({duration:opts.slideUpDuration, easing:opts.slideUpEasing});//hides the current dropdown
                activeNav = null;
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({dropDownWidth: '300px'});
});
```

Were am I messing up the code and how could I make it work or how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! As you are new, please be aware that we have some general guidelines to help maintain a certain level of quality on this site. One is to put code in the question itself if at all possible. Questions with only links to jsfiddle present a [whole host of issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/191410). It also helps if you can narrow the scope of your question: "please debug this for me" is simply too broad to be of use to future visitors. See [Does SO discourage questions like "this is my code, please find the bug"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37308/191410)

Comment: For a better discussion of "link-only questions", please see [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/191410)

Comment: Cyborgx37, you are right in what you say. I read that before posting the question but when I reviewed it I did not realized the problem, forgive me.         The real problem I have is that in the second link to the code the menu looks awfull overlapping itself and what is more, the deployable menu has a submenu which I want to be deployable and it does not work at all.        I have been stucked with this problems for days asking friends what the problem seems to be but neither them nor me found it. So the question is were am I messing up the code and how could I make it work or how to fix it.

Comment: Cyborgx37 has a point. Before reopening this question please can you edit it to include the *minimal* amount of HTML and JavaScript needed to reproduce your problem. A link to jsfiddle is great, but it should supplement the code in your question, not be the only code. When you've done that feel free to flag for reopening if it doesn't happen from community votes. Until you show the code in the question I won't be voting to reopen it though and posting the links inside a code block is cheating.

Comment: What you mean by saying cheating? Posting links like I did is what stackoverflow said as suggestion when making the post. Is there anything else that its not at suggested? Since I want no problems nor I wanted al this to happen. Thanks in advance, Martin.

Comment: "Cheating" means that when the system tells to post code along with the jsfiddle links, please do so instead of formatting the links as code to get around the error message. But the code is there now, although there's so much of it that you'd probably get the question opened more likely if you pruned it down to the smallest amount of code that still shows the problem.

Comment: @Juhana what is the right way to put jsfiddle links then? The code I posted is everything I put in the webpage except for the part of <head> and <body> since it is a deployable menu in a hole webpage. Any sugestions? Thanks in advance, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I only got closed the threat and they told me a lot of stuff I made wrong by posting but still no help. To many days past through and I managed to help other people and myself with problems we all have and with my tiny easy problem nobody got even interested...
I suggest the community and the administrators of this site to clarify yourselves how to improve this in order to get it working the way it should, otherwise do not be so harsh on the people that post things like I did or change the theme of the website from "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." to "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional" since you give not even a clue to some easy topics.

Sincerely, Martin

P.S.: I post this to generate self conscience of the real problem of the site in order to improve it, do not mean to get anyone furious.